# Shell script to recursively rename filenames with special characters escaped?

Tags: php, linux, bash

Php has a method `escapeshellcmd()` that escapes any characters in a string that might be used to trick a shell command into executing arbitrary commands.

```
<?php
exec(find /music -type f -iname '*mp3'", $arrSongPaths);
echo $arrSongPaths[0] //prints It WonÃ‚Â´t Be Long.mp3;
echo escapeshellcmd($arrSongPaths[0]) //prints It Wont Be Long.mp3;
?>
```

Is there a way to write a shell script that will recursively rename filenames (in particular *mp3) with special characters escaped?

I tried to do this in php

```
$escapedSongPath = escapeshellarg($arrSongPaths[0]);    
exec("mv $arrSongPaths[0] $escapedSongPath");
```

but that didn't work.  Anyways the last line of code is unsafe since you're executing a command with a potentially dangerous filename `$arrSongPaths[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the love of all things security related why aren't you using the php `rename` command - it doesn't suffer from any shell escape issues. replace the `exec("mv ...")` with:

```
rename($arrSongPaths[0], $escapedSongPath)
```

... and check for errors.

And instead of using `exec(find...)` use the `recursive_glob` tip from the [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) php operation page.

Comment: Thank Petesh, is there a reason `recursive_glob` is preferred to `exec(find...)`?

Comment: It's not that one is preferred over the other, it's just that everything that you're doing is doable without leaving php, so keep the implementation in php. The only reason for calling out to the shell should only be for tasks that cannot be done in php. Whenever you cross languages using something like exec() it requires a lot of work to make sure it works, and also that it works safely. e.g. a track called `; rm -rf /;.mp3` in your original implementation would have tried to wipe your hard drive, but would get renamed to `\; rm -rf /\; .mp3` with the built in rename.